# add font path for font server

Tags: x11, fonts, sysvinit

I have installed on Debian Sid the `xfstt` font server to permit to really old programs to access `.ttf` fonts using the XLFD format.

After a reboot the `xfstt` is started via SYS V's init and figures in `sysctl` list of running services

```
$ systemctl --all | grep xfstt
  xfstt.service           loaded    active   running   LSB: xfstt sysv init script
```

When I try to add the font server to my font path an error occurs, irrespective of prepending or appending the font server to the path

```
$ xset fp+ unix/:7101
xset:  bad font path element (#7), possible causes are:
    Directory does not exist or has wrong permissions
    Directory missing fonts.dir
    Incorrect font server address or syntax
$ xset +fp unix/:7101
xset:  bad font path element (#0), possible causes are:
    Directory does not exist or has wrong permissions
    Directory missing fonts.dir
    Incorrect font server address or syntax
```

This method of setting the font path is documented in the man page

> `Xfstt  serves  TrueType fonts to X11 servers. Start xfstt then tell X11 about the font server with xset fp+ unix/:7101`

As far as I can tell the font server has been synced with the TT fonts present on my system, as `/var/cache/xfstt/` contains two `.dir`files containg names of TT fonts with time stamps compatible with the installation of the package.

<strike>I cannot say for certain on which port `xfstt` is listening but scanning the init script</strike>

```
$ grep 7101 /etc/init.d/xfstt 
portno=7101
```

led me to think that `xfstt` is on the default port.

I have installed `x11-xfs-utils` and now I can say with certainty that
`xfstt` is running, listening on port `7101` and that it knows about (at least some of) my `.ttf` fonts:

```
$ xfsinfo -server unix/:7101
name of server: unix/:7101
version number: 2
vendor string:  HD
vendor release number:  1
maximum request size:   1024 longwords (8192 bytes)
number of catalogues:   0
Number of alternate servers: 0
number of extensions:   0
$ fslsfonts -server unix/:7101| wc -l
692
$ fslsfonts -server unix/:7101| tail -2
TTUP040605050702030202040_EB Garamond Initials Fill2
TTUP050100000000000000000_OpenSymbol
```

What  have  I to do to use correctly the *running* font server?

Comment: Have you tried using `xset fp` with the configured port number? `xset fp+ unix/:7101` presumably.

Comment: @StephenKitt Ooops, I ran the commands using `7100` but that was a mistake, originated by me trying different ports to see if one worked maybe... I have edited the question to reflect the fact that using `7101` as intended raised an error.  Thank you for spotting the problem.

Comment: I am not sure font servers are even supported by newer xorgs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Font_Server seem to support this suspicion.